# Hooking up multiple NSViewControllers to a nib

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, appkit

I have a window that contains several rather complex views. Right now, I'm using a single NSWindowController to control the UI for the window and all the views. It's becoming a pretty huge class, since it's dealing with the details of each and every view.

The view behaviors are independent from one another though, so I see an opportunity to put the UI logic for each view into a separate controller.

According to the [Mac App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html), this is exactly what view controllers are for:

> Use view controllers to divide up the work for managing more
>   sophisticated window layouts. Your view controllers work together
>   (with the window controller) to present the window contents.

However, I can't find any documentation or examples on how this idea works in practice. Can I add multiple view controllers to the nib file in addition to the window controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the view controllers to the nib, that's where they're going to be instantiated, and you'd add `IBOutlet`s to the window controller (assuming that's the nib's File's Owner) in order to connect them.

In terms of memory, however, that scheme could become expensive, especially the more view controllers you have. You may want to instead consider lazily instantiating them in the window controller, (i.e., doing so only when needed), assuming this doesn't result in an objectionable lag before the view is presented for the first time.

Don't be afraid to try both approaches. One of them may be best for you.

In any case, I applaud you for your decision to factor out all that code into separate controllers. Very nice. Good luck to you in your endeavors.